# What is the statistical difference between "choose either total" or "choose new total" when rerolling damage die?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, statistics

I am reworking a homebrew class I made a while ago where one class feature stated:

> when making a melee attack you can choose to reroll the damage die. The new total must be used.

I wanted to make this a bit stronger by making it into:

> when making a melee attack you can choose to reroll the damage die. You can use either total

I was wondering what is the difference in terms of damage when making them use the new total vs picking what total to use.

I am not asking for the balance aspect of this feature, just the numerical, statistical difference between the two options.

Comment: @NautArch It is about melee attacks, that can be from 1d4 to 2d6

Comment: @darnok So any standard melee weapon (as found in PHB). There are melee spell attacks which can deal other dice (as in 3d6 etc).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Mathematically, "either total" is 4%~6% better than "take new total".

I made a spreadsheet where I compare this using a d6. The columns represent the value you rolled on a d6, so 1 to 6. The rows represent the value rolled on the second d6 (if you did re-roll). The value in the matrix is the actual end-value taken from rolling the die/dice.

[image]

If you get to choose either total, you will always roll twice and pick the best, as shown below. The average result here is 4.47.

[image]

If you pick the new total, it only makes sense to re-roll when you roll a 1, 2, or 3 on the first die (since those values are worse than the average value for a d6). As you see below, in the columns for 4, 5, and 6, you don't re-roll, and keep the value. On the others, you re-roll and get the new value (1 to 6). The average here is 4.25.

[image]

So, on a d6, if choosing "either total" represents on average a 4.47, and taking the "new total" represents on average a 4.25, then there is a 5% improvement in being able to choose either total.

Running a simple [python script](https://pastebin.com/GZwRyCP5) shows you the improvements for:

- d4: 4.17%
- d6: 5.23%
- 2d6: 5.01%
- d8: 5.68%
- d10: 5.93%
- d12: 6.08%
- d20: 6.35%

That being said, this assumes there is no limitation on using this feature. If it is more limited, you might just re-roll when you get low values, and that will skew the averages I've shown. As [R..](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/15902/r) pointed out,

> "New total" also has much higher risk, making it reasonable to decline to use it in cases where your initial roll is somewhat below the mean if a very low re-roll would be catastrophically worse than the initial low roll. Both the risk itself and any hesitance to take a re-roll due to the risk are factors that increase the advantage of the "choose either roll" variant.

Comment: I wrote an [anydice program](https://anydice.com/program/17765) to do this comparison quickly for any given dice expression. Observation: as a general rule, the relative improvement in average output is proportional to the standard deviation of the result, e.g. large single dice offer a greater improvement, dice pools with a pronounced bell curve less so. If you run it with a 1d100 you'll see about a 9.4% improvement.

Comment: "New total" also has much higher risk, making it reasonable to decline to use it in cases where your initial roll is somewhat below the mean if a very low re-roll would be catastrophically worse than the initial low roll. Both the risk itself and any hesitance to take a re-roll due to the risk are factors that increase the advantage of the "choose either roll" variant.

Comment: @carcer perhaps I don't understand anydice but why don't you simply remove the [rerollnew] function entirely, and just have the line "output [rerollnewhelper DICE DICE]"? https://anydice.com/program/17792

Comment: @R.. I've added your comment to the answer, very insightful

Comment: @Medix2 that also works fine, I just wanted to write it so that the directly used functions all took the same single argument format.